# Using a list in a text file as a list in Latex \foreach loop

Tags: input, foreach, latex

Sorry if I didn't tag\classify this well. But here is my problem

I have a list generated by another program which goes into a text file, when I want to simply include this text in my latex document i use \input{writing.txt} this works fine.

The issue i'm having is figuring out a way to use a text file that has a list like

picnname1 picname2 picname2 ... and have latex recognize that as my list, included in \input{list.txt}

Below is a broken example, which works when I replace \input{list.txt} with the actual list. My attempts so far have gotten me nowhere. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{python}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[space]{grffile}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[top=2cm]{geometry}

    \foreach \picname in {\input{list.txt}}
    { 
    \section{\MakeUppercase\picname}
     \begin{figure}[h]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=10cm]{\picname_Main.pdf}
     \caption{This depicts the trend in \picname}
     \end{figure}



    \input{"filepathforsometext"\picname.txt}
    \input{"filepathforatable"\picname_GrowthTable}
    \input{"filepathforanothertable"\picname_ActualPop}
      \clearpage
     }


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you also provide an example of the file containing your list? I think the Markdown here may have formatted it incorrectly.

Comment: Sure, and this is something I could vary if formatting the list in a particular way would be useful. Right now the file containing the list is a .txt file which just contains the following: Location1 Location2 Location3 etc. Basically the list of locations with a space between each, and no punctuation.

Comment: ...and no location name with a space between it. That is, NewYork Boston Philadelphia, ... instead of New York, Boston, Philadelphia, ...